# Create and deploy an EJB application on glassfish / wildfly

Tags: java, servlets, glassfish, ejb, ejb-3.0

For the past couple of days I've been playing with EJB's and trying to deploy my project to actually see if it works..

What I'm trying to do is this:

I created an EJB project in which I have two Entities (Student and Grade) and the local and remote bean.
Now, I want to create a Servlet along with a jsp file to add Students and Grades into the Database through a web form.

I feel a little lost in this steps of working with EJB. Should I create another project in which I integrate the ejb jar in order to work with it in a Servlet?
Also, how to I deploy a project like this on a Glassfish / wildfly server independent from an IDE?
If someone can bring some light on what are the steps of doing this, it will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to have a separate project for EJBs.
Create a web application project and put your EJB classes along with your Servlet classes.

Compile and put the war (eg. mywebapp.war) file into the standalone/deployment directory of your wildfly installation.

Now, access your servlets from a browser:

> http://localhost:8080/mywebapp/*servlet/path*

Comment: in j2ee application is not good to put ejb with web application in the same project , u can use module with maven for ejb module ejbclient module web module ... for many reason we most do that, but for simple project we can do that u say